# Sql View : Column Header having dynamic date

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I need to do this in excel: 4 column having date of passed week (today is 19-07-2018, so the first will 12-07-2018). the report from Sql is connected via ODBC and when it is opened the column header should consider this range using the current date as a referred day.

[image]

I'm not able to find code to insert in the select this dates. If I try in Excel, the report take 2 minutes to refresh data on the sheets. So only idea I have is replicate the report in SQL, having a view. Do you have a solution for me different from declare a variable and execute it, please? I really appreciate it.
(in use Sql 2012)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are looking to do.  Do you mean that we should take a SQL report and just add a row to the top with the dates from last week?  Or are we looking at a field from the SQL report and adjusting the dates it gives us?

Answer (score 0):

You can have an imaginary column in your data on the fly that would serve as a "week grouping" column. It contains the "first day of the week". You select your data as "Attribute, WeekGroup, Value" from SQL server and PIVOT this data in Excel (excel really shines in pivoting the data so you don't need to pivot in SQL - pass raw data and pivot there instead). In pivoting "Attribute" is the Row field, "week" go into column field and data is value (probably you would want SUM which is the default, if not specify your calculation).

[Here is a sample in SQLFiddle for the data and Query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bd52d4/1/0)

EDIT: Pasting the query here too just thinking SQLFiddle link may get lost:

```
WITH dates (d)
AS (SELECT TOP (7 * 4)
           DATEADD(d, -7 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.object_id), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
    FROM sys.objects t1,
         sys.objects t2),
     mondays
AS (SELECT d
    FROM dates
    WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, d) = 'Monday')
SELECT t.attribute,
       m.d AS [week],
       t.value
FROM myTable t
    INNER JOIN mondays m
        ON t.dt >= m.d
           AND t.dt < DATEADD(d, 7, m.d)
ORDER BY t.attribute,
         d,
         dt;
```

Comment: yep i think this is the best solution i can choose.Thank you very much for your help , and sorry for this delay in my reply